# Merge 2 rules FormFequest for validate an update and store action in laravel5.5

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-validation, laravel-request

I have 2 `FormRequest` classes (`ReadersFormRequest`, `SocialMediaFormRequest`) and I want to store and update a `Reader`. A `Reader` may have 0 or many social media accounts, so it's necessary to validate the request.

**ReadersFormRequest**

```
class ReadersFormRequest extends FormRequest
{
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'first_name'=>'required',
            'last_name'=>'required',
            'birthday'=>'required',
            'region'=>'required',
            'photo_url'=>'required',
            'support'=>'required',
            'riwayas_id'=>'required',
            'description'=>'required',
        ];
    }
}
```

**SocialMediaFormRequest**

```
 public function rules()
 {
    return [
        'url'=>'required|url',
        'title'=>'required'
    ];
 }
```

So I want to merge the `SocialMediaFormRequest` rules in `ReadersFormRequest` rules

I found a solution:

- make SocialMediaFormRequest rules a static method and merge it in SocialMediaFormRequest rules

**SocialMediaFormRequest**

```
public static function rules()
{
    return [
        'url'=>'required|url',
        'title'=>'required'
    ];
}
```

**ReadersFormRequest**

```
public function rules()
{
    return array_merge(SocialMediaFormRequest::rules(),[
        'first_name'=>'required',
        'last_name'=>'required',
        'birthday'=>'required',
        'region'=>'required',
        'photo_url'=>'required',
        'support'=>'required',
        'riwayas_id'=>'required',
        'description'=>'required',
    ]);
}
```

I think the merge is correctly done, but in update controller when I call this `ReadersFormRequest`, I don't know what happens.

```
public function update(ReadersFormRequest $request, Readers $reader)
{
    // valid and update reader
    Readers::whereId($reader->id)->update([
        'first_name' => $request->validated()['first_name'],
        'last_name' => $request->validated()['last_name'],
        'photo_url' => $request->validated()['photo_url'],
        'birthday' => $request->validated()['birthday'],
        'region' => $request->validated()['region'],
        'support' => $request->validated()['support'],
        'riwayas_id' => $request->validated()['riwayas_id'],
        'description' => $request->validated()['description']
    ]);
    // For update their social media account links 
    foreach ($request->validated()['url'] as $key => $url)
    {

    }

    return redirect(route('readers.show',$reader));
}
```

When I PUT the reader form this controller is not called.

Comment: dumb question, why don't you just copy the lines to the other class?

Comment: @madalinivascu  I want the project be organized and use OOP completly

Comment: so you want to say copying the fields from one class to another is not "OOP" ?

Comment: what does `$request->validated()['first_name']` do?

Comment: it means i validate the 'first_name' comming from request

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alter your class to:

```
class ReadersFormRequest extends FormRequest
{
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'first_name'=>'required',
            'last_name'=>'required',
            'birthday'=>'required',
            'region'=>'required',
            'photo_url'=>'required',
            'support'=>'required',
            'riwayas_id'=>'required',
            'description'=>'required',
            'url'=>'required|url',
            'title'=>'required'
        ];
    }
}
```

or if you really want to use a class do:

```
class ReadersFormRequest extends FormRequest
{
    public function rules(SocialMediaFormRequest $social)
    { 
        $mediaRules = $social->rules();
        $rules = [
            'first_name'=>'required',
            'last_name'=>'required',
            'birthday'=>'required',
            'region'=>'required',
            'photo_url'=>'required',
            'support'=>'required',
            'riwayas_id'=>'required',
            'description'=>'required',
        ];
        return array_merge($rules,$mediaRules);
    }
}
```

Comment: i wana really use  the class SocialMediaFormRequest 
and it don't work too  even the controller don't work and  error just same at refresh page no result

Comment: the problem no problem displayed but no accesses to  the ReadersController

Comment: what do you mean by **no accesses to the ReadersController**?

Comment: The given data was invalid.D:\Users\Haithem Dissem\Desktop\blog\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest.php#117Illuminate\Validation\ValidationException
------------------------------------     
    protected function failedValidation(Validator $validator)
    {
        throw (new ValidationException($validator))
                    ->errorBag($this->errorBag)
                    ->redirectTo($this->getRedirectUrl());
    }
this is the  exception

Comment: I solved the problem. It was the validation of SocialMediaFormRequest rules().
        'url'=>'required|url', ----------become---------->           'url'=>'required',

Comment: This way of doing requires having a **media**. Do you know a way that would allow **media** to be **null**? I ask the question because currently, even if **media is null**, it will call to the media request, which I don't want since it is null.

Answer (score 0):

This's how I handled it in similar situation:

```
public static function combineValidations($rules1, $rules2)
{
    if(!is_array($rules2)) return $rules1;

    foreach($rules2 as $key => $item)
    {
        if(!isset($rules1[$key]))
        {
            $rules1[$key] = $item;
        }else
        {
            $rules1[$key] .= '|'.$item;
        }
    }

    return $rules1;
}
```