# Merge FormRequest rules

Tags: laravel, forms

This question is based on this thread: [Merge 2 rules FormFequest for validate an update and store action in laravel5.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46952609/merge-2-rules-formfequest-for-validate-an-update-and-store-action-in-laravel5-5)

Context: Let's suppose I have these 2 requests and I want to merge the `SocialMediaFormRequest` rules in `ReadersFormRequest` rules.

**ReadersFormRequest**

```
class ReadersFormRequest extends FormRequest
{
    public function rules(SocialMediaFormRequest $social)
    { 
        $mediaRules = $social->rules();
        $rules = [
            'first_name'=>'required',
            'last_name'=>'required',
            'birthday'=>'required',
            'region'=>'required',
            'photo_url'=>'required',
            'support'=>'required',
            'riwayas_id'=>'required',
            'description'=>'required',
        ];
        return array_merge($rules,$mediaRules);
    }
}
```

**SocialMediaFormRequest**

```
class SocialMediaFormRequest extends FormRequest
{

    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'url'=>'required|url',
            'title'=>'required'
        ];
    }
}
```

**Form that I received**

```
first_name: "example"
last_name: "example"
birthday: 2022-06-13
region: somewhere
photo_url: "https:XXX"
support: false
riwayas_id: 1
description: ""
media.url: "https:YYY"
media.title: "stackoverflow"
```

Question: How can I only pass the argument `media.XXX` in my form `SocialMediaFormRequest`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `prepareForValidation()` method in the form request to sanitize the inputs : https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation#preparing-input-for-validation

So, if in **SocialMediaFormRequest** you receive the full request you can only get the required fields like that:

```
    public function prepareForValidation()
    {
        $this->replace([
            'url' => $this->url ?? ($this->media['url'] ?? null),
            'title' => $this->title ?? ($this->media['title'] ?? null),
        ]);
    }
```

Also, in **ReadersFormRequest** when you inject the other request or resolve it from the container it doesn't work correctly, so it is better to get the rules like that:

```
public function rules()
{ 
     $mediaRules = (new SocialMediaFormRequest())->rules();
```

and in order to access the media.* attributes in **ReadersFormRequest** you can again use prepareForValidation:

```
public function prepareForValidation()
{
    $this->merge([
        'url' => $this->media['url'] ?? null,
        'title' => $this->media['title'] ?? null,
    ]);
}
```

Comment: If you mean that prepareForValidation() should go in my **ReadersFormRequest**, that's not a good idea, because SocialMediaFormRequest will receive some value (like first_name, last_name, birthday, etc) that it should not receive.


If you mean that prepareForValidation() should go in my **SocialMediaFormRequest**, then what would happen when I use another form that directly contain "url, title"? Since we use merge, it should change nothing, but I ask just to be sure.
Also, SocialMediaFormRequest will still receive value from ReadersFormRequest and it should not receive them.

Comment: @jeremiebergeron - edited my answer with the considerations from your comment

Comment: Thank you! However, **$mediaRules = (new SocialMediaFormRequest())->rules();** seems to not initialized the request correctly, because when I debug it, I can see that it has no parameter (it should have url and title). But, if I keep what I already wrote in my ReadersFormRequest, it work without any problem.

Comment: The idea is that all the validations happen inside the ReadersFormRequest, from SocialMediaFormRequest you only get the rules and add them in the current request. As I tested if you inject the request and you have failed validations from both rulesets, only the media.* will be displayed in your form. Of course, if you have additional logic in your SocialMediaFormRequest, leave it as it is, just keep it mind that behavior.

Comment: *The idea is that all the validations happen inside the ReadersFormRequest, from SocialMediaFormRequest you only get the rules and add them in the current request.*

I am totally agree with you, but if I wrote **$mediaRules = (new SocialMediaFormRequest())->rules();**, I can see with the debugger that my SocialMediaFormRequest instance has no parameter, so it always that it missed some fields.